# How to generate a schema for a custom pagination in django rfw with drf-spectacular?

Tags: django-rest-framework, pagination, swagger, drf-spectacular

I am struggling to properly generate the schema for my custom pagination in django rest framework.
I am using drf-spectacular for the schema generation. My custom pagination includes a *total-pages* field which does not come with djangos PageNumberPagination.
The response is correctly serialized and returned and includes the *total-pages*, but the schema in my swagger docs does not include the field.
Here is my code:

*pagination.py*

```
from rest_framework import pagination
from rest_framework.response import Response

class CustomPagination(pagination.PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 10
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
    max_page_size = 100
    page_query_param = 'p'
    
    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        return Response({
            'page_size': self.page_size,
            'total_objects': self.page.paginator.count,
            'total_pages': self.page.paginator.num_pages,
            'current_page_number': self.page.number,
            'next': self.get_next_link(),
            'previous': self.get_previous_link(),
            'results': data,
        })
```

Here is my view:

*views.py*

```
@extend_schema_view(
    get=extend_schema(
        parameters=[OpenApiParameter("q", OpenApiTypes.STR, OpenApiParameter.QUERY),],
        request=TestStandardSearchSerializer,
        responses=TestStandardSerializer
        )
    )
class TestStandardSearchView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = TestStandardSearchSerializer
    queryset = TestStandard.objects.all()
    pagination_class = CustomPagination
   
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        query = self.request.query_params.get('q')
        queryset = SearchQuerySet().all().filter(content=query).order_by('acronym')
        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
        return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
    
    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.method == 'GET':
           return TestStandardSearchSerializer
```

The response schema from my swagger doc is the following:

```
PaginatedTestStandardList
{
count   integer                            example: 123
next    string($uri)     nullable: true    example: http://api.example.org/accounts/?p=4
previous    string($uri) nullable: true    example: http://api.example.org/accounts/?p=2
results [TestStandard{...}]
}
```

The standard django pagination is correctly ínserted in the schema, but not my custom pagination response.
What I expected/wanted is to have my customized pagination response correctly integrated with the *total-pages* field on the same level as 'count', 'next' and 'previous'.

What I tried...
I have a working solution with *drf_yasg* using the PaginatorInspector providing a custom schema. But this is not available in *drf-spectacular*.
I also used *inline_serializer* with a custom response in *@extend_schema_view* such as:

```
responses={
            200: inline_serializer(
           name='PaginatedTestStandardSearchResponse',
           fields={
               'total-pages': serializers.IntegerField(),
               'results': TestStandardSearchSerializer()
           },
```

This resulted in a schema where *total-pages* is nested within results.
I am using:

```
drf-spectacular     0.21.2
Django              3.2.12
django-rest-swagger 2.2.0
djangorestframework 3.12.4
```

Any help is appreciated. I just recently started with django rfw and openapi schema generation. Sorry if I had missed something obvious here.

Answer (score 9):

You need to overwrite the method `get_paginated_response_schema` in your CustomPagination. For the reference about how to compose it, you can see it on file pagination.py inside rest_framework package.

If you want to know how does that works, you could find it inside drf-spectacular package on file openapi.py, method _get_response_for_code. I hope that solve your problem.

Comment: It worked. Thank you. I looked into djangos pagination.py and wrote a new get_paginated_response_schema(self, schema). 
Is there an efficient way to append the base pagination schema? I ended up copying the code from djangos base function and inserting my total pages. I post my final funtion in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up with overwriting get_paginated_response().
This finally resolved my issue. Now the correct pagination parameters are shown in the swagger documentation.

This is my custom paginator:

```
   from rest_framework import pagination
   from rest_framework.response import Response

   class CustomPagination(pagination.PageNumberPagination):
       page_size = 10
       page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
       max_page_size = 100
       page_query_param = 'p'
    
       def get_paginated_response(self, data):
           print(data)
           print()
           return Response({
               'count': self.page.paginator.count,
               'next': self.get_next_link(),
               'previous': self.get_previous_link(),
               'page_size': self.page_size,
               'total_objects': self.page.paginator.count,
               'total_pages': self.page.paginator.num_pages,
               'current_page_number': self.page.number,
               'results': data,
           })
    
      def get_paginated_response_schema(self, schema):            
          return {
              'type': 'object',
              'properties': {
                  'count': {
                      'type': 'integer',
                      'example': 123,
                  },
                  'next': {
                      'type': 'string',
                      'nullable': True,
                      'format': 'uri',
                      'example': 'http://api.example.org/accounts/? 
                          {page_query_param}=4'.format(
                          page_query_param=self.page_query_param)
                  },
                  'previous': {
                      'type': 'string',
                      'nullable': True,
                      'format': 'uri',
                      'example': 'http://api.example.org/accounts/? 
                          {page_query_param}=2'.format(
                          page_query_param=self.page_query_param)
                  },                
                  'page_size' : {
                      'type': 'integer',
                      'example': 123,
                  },
                  'total_pages': {
                      'type': 'integer',
                      'example': 123,
                  },
                  'current_page_number': {
                      'type': 'integer',
                      'example': 123,
                  },
                  'results': schema,
              },
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

I followed the [@Agung Wiyono advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71590360/21272817) when faced with the same issue of total pages, and the following code worked for me. It is almost the same code as [@Anti provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71621670/21272817), but with the use of `super`. This way, we only modify base methods without completely rewriting them.

```
class PageNumberPaginationWithCount(pagination.PageNumberPagination):
    def get_paginated_response(self, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super(PageNumberPaginationWithCount, self).get_paginated_response(*args, **kwargs)
        response.data['total_pages'] = self.page.paginator.num_pages
        return response

    def get_paginated_response_schema(self, *args, **kwargs):
        schema = super(PageNumberPaginationWithCount, self).get_paginated_response_schema(*args, **kwargs)
        schema['properties']['total_pages'] = {
            'type': 'integer',
            'example': 123,
        }
        return schema
```

Comment: Is there a way to remove some of the fields form the super class.

IE: super has `next_page: http://exmaple.com?page=2`

i want to remove that one

Comment: It seems, that popping unnecessary fields will work either: `response.data.pop('next')` in `get_paginated_response` and `schema['properties'].pop('next')`  in `get_paginated_response_schema`. But an additional research may be needed, as a super class might expect the presence of removed fields somewhere...